# Connection Error on a PostgreSQL x64 9.5 database from ArcGIS Pro 1.3.0

Tags: postgis, postgresql, arcgis-pro

I have the following PostgreSQL database named "**cfa_fem_gc**":

```
CREATE DATABASE cfa_fem_gc
  WITH OWNER = gc
       ENCODING = 'UTF8'
       TABLESPACE = pg_default
       LC_COLLATE = 'English_Australia.1252'
       LC_CTYPE = 'English_Australia.1252'
       CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;

ALTER DATABASE cfa_fem_gc
  SET search_path = "$user", public, tiger, sde;
```

It was enabled with PostGIS 2.3 and all GIS data has been stored on the "**gc**" schema with the owner "**gc**".

**I do not have any difficulty connecting to the database and viewing the shapefile on QGIS.**

However, a connection error was thrown from **ArcGIS Pro 1.3** if I tried to make a new Database Connection and connect to the cfa_fem_gc database.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that PostgreSQL/PostGIS version combination is supported by ArcGIS Pro 2.1 - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/databases/database-requirements-postgresql.htm - but have you checked "PostgreSQL database requirements for ArcGIS Pro 1.3"?  I could not find that page online but if you are still using 1.3 perhaps you have the offline help.

Comment: Pro 1.3 was Retired two months ago. As best I could tell, it  corresponded to ArcGIS 10.3.x, which did not support PostgreSQL 9.5 (not until ArcGIS 10.5) nor PostGIS 2.3 (which isn't supported by ArcGIS until 10.6, and only with PG 9.6.3+).  Please be sure to place error messages in the body of the question as text, so that it is both legible and searchable.